# Can't remove HDRI lighting

Tags: lighting, hdri

I can't seem to remove the lighting that the HDRI I used to have loaded into the file contained. I have completely removed the entire world shader (as well as all other objects in the file), but it still shows the old hdri lighting. Any idea where I might be going wrong in this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzeSE.jpg

Comment: You are in Material Preview mode which uses a hidden HDRI for lighting and reflections. Press Z in the viewport and select "Rendered" from the pie menu, or select the rightmost of the 4 circles in the top-right of the viewport (render preview) to see your own lighting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're correct that I was in the wrong preview mode. However, even in render mode, it still appears the same. I've attached a screenshot showing even in render mode, a "cube" still appears lit.

Also, I'm in eevee. It seems to matter, because cycles does appear 100% dark.

https://imgur.com/a/3bl4Wjt

Answer (score 0):

[image: Make sure it is set like this]

Make sure that Scene Lights and Scene World is checked